# Is it possible that keyboard change iOS app orientation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a problem.

In my app I have a view with some textfields in it. 
I use the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method for change orientation. Additionally i update the textfields frames for portrait and landscape mode.

When I set landscape mode in app, everything works great until I tap in some textfield and the keyboard shows up. After that textfields frames return to Portrait mode (but only the frames of textfields and labels).

Also it happens when I rotate to landscape in parent view and go to my view with the textfields.

Is it possible that the keyboard changes iOS app orientation? I would be greatfull for some advice.

Code (I do it in parent view and second view):

In viewDidLoad:

```
[self setFramesForInterface:self.interfaceOrientation];
```

Methods:

```
- (void)setFramesForInterface:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {

switch (toInterfaceOrientation) {
    case UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown:
        [self setFramesForPortrait];
        break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        [self setFramesForPortrait];
        break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        [self setFramesForPortrait];
        break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        [self setFramesForLandscapeLeft];
        break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        [self setFramesForLandscapeLeft];
        break;
    default:
        break;
} }

- (void)setFramesForPortrait {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [_stationNameLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(8, 40, 105, 30)];
    [_addresLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(8, 85, 105, 30)];
    .........................
}); }

- (void)setFramesForLandscapeLeft {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [_stationNameLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(8, 20, 105, 30)];
    [_addresLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(8, 65, 105, 30)];
    ...................
}); }

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
[super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
[self setFramesForInterface:toInterfaceOrientation];}
```

Comment: "Is it possible that the keyboard changes iOS app orientation" No, it is not. You must be doing something else wrong. Show code if you want help. - By the way, in iOS 8 you should not be using `willRotate` (but you need it if this app also runs in iOS 7).

Comment: Excellent. Now: "I tap in some textfield and the keyboard shows up. After that textfields frames return to Portrait mode" So does this mean that your `setFramesForInterface:` is being called when the keyboard appears? If so, you need to find out who is calling it! Set a breakpoint and look at the call stack.

Comment: I did it and `setFramesForInterface:` is not calling by any methods when I tap texfield.

Comment: Excellent again! I'm ready to give an answer (might be right or wrong, but you've now given good info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you're using auto layout. That is the source of the issue.

You cannot reposition / resize things using `setFrame:` when using auto layout. You must change the *constraints* instead.

Well, you *can* use `setFrame:`, but it is sort of pointless, because the constraints are the important thing. When layout comes along, for any reason, the constraints are obeyed. So what's happening to you is: you change the frame, but then you cause layout to be triggered and the constraints take over, moving everything back into its original place.

Comment: Yes, my answer is advising you to change your `setFramesForPortrait` and `setFramesForLandscapeLeft` so that what they change is _constraints_, not frame.

Comment: I unchcecked "Use Auto Layout" and It work, thanks ;)

Comment: No, unchecking Use Auto Layout is not a good solution. You should _learn_ Auto Layout, not avoid it.

Comment: I know, but it's a college project which should be made so ;)